# XML Http Response Not allowing xml parsing

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am writing an AJAX postcode look up script and I am having problems with the responseXML part.

I can get the responseXML and it shows the response using an alert() but when I try to get specific node values I get errors specifically SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementByTagName'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var xmlhttp; 

function doLookup() {

    var postcodetosearch = document.getElementById("ctl00_pageContent_txtPostalCode").value;
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("ctl00_pageContent_postCodeLookupContainer");
    mydiv.style.display = "inline";



    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var response = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            var myresponse1;

            myresponse1 = response.xml 

            myresponse1 = "<p>" + response.getElementByTagName("street")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

            document.getElementById("postcoderesult").innerHTML = myresponse1;

        }
    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://geo.jamiethompson.co.uk/" + postcodetosearch + ".xml",false);

    xmlhttp.send(null);
}


</script>
```

Can someone guide me?

Comment: Use code formatting in your post, it's hard to see what you have there.

Comment: Put some effort into your post. It is I not i! I edited it and fixed the code. And as I said on the ASP.NET forums, use the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: Do you do a cross-domain request? If so, the server needs to support [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method as `getElementByTagName` (with the word "Element" as singular). It's `getElementsByTagName` (with the word "Elements" as plural; [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)).